# Distributed Training with Tensorflow in AMLS

Tags: distributed-computing, tensorflow-estimator, azure-machine-learning-service

using a TensorFlow estimator in Azure ML Service with the following config.

```
from azureml.core.runconfig import TensorflowConfiguration
distributed_training = TensorflowConfiguration()
distributed_training.worker_count = 3
est = TensorFlow(source_directory=script_folder,
             script_params=script_params,
             compute_target=compute_target,
             node_count=4,
             distributed_training=distributed_training,
             use_gpu=True,
             entry_script=train_script)
run = exp.submit(est)
```

It seems like in the run with this configuration, individual workers come up with their own instances of trained models and try to register the model multiple times. Is Distributed Training something I need to deal with in the Tensorflow training script?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to handle the model saving in training script: gather the model coefficients to a single rank, and save them to file from that rank.

You can then register the model outside the training script, using run.register_model and passing the folder / file of the saved model as an argument.